# Shouldn't Rails find_by_ methods return an empty array instead of nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, null

Shouldn't Rails find_by_ methods return an empty array instead of nil?

It's normal for there to be no records that match the find_by_ condition, but returning nil doesn't make sense. Because then in my views errors are raised by sensible code like:

```
<% for thing in @thing_that_might_be_an_array_or_might_be_nil do %>
```

Since find_by_ always returns an array, even if there's only 1 record, it should also return an array if there are 0 records. Then all those

```
<% @thing.each
```

and

```
<% for thing in @thing
```

in our views will quietly get passed over instead of causing a **"We're sorry, but something went wrong."** (or what am I missing? what's the current best practice of dealing with this?)

Comment: And in Rails 4, all this is moot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find_by_` is used to find one record, the first one that matches your conditions.

`find_all_by_` is used to find a set of records, an array, that match your conditions.

So, yes, I think it's totally normal for `find_by_` to return nil, and not an empty array,  when it doesn't find anything, because you're only asking for one thing.